# Template view changes iterating through JSON object when index goes beyond 10

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I have JSON object like this.

```
{
CR1: "aaa"
CR2: "bbb*2"
CR3: "ccc/2"
CR4: "ddd-23"
CR5: ""
CR6: "SS"
CR7: ""
}
```

The index after 'CR' is added dynamically and in template when iterated using `ngFor` it takes view as below:

[image]

But when CR index goes above 10 the view changes something like this:

[image: CR10, CR11 should be added after CR9 not CR1]

Here is code from template:

```
<div class="row mt-10" *ngFor="let item of computationLogicObj | keyvalue; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="field_{{item.key}}">{{item.key}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{item.key}}" name="{{item.key}}" [(ngModel)]="computationLogicObj[item.key]" [disabled]="!isInternal">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a (click)="deleteComputationLogic(item.key)">
            <fa-icon [icon]="'times'"></fa-icon>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and `trackByFn`

```
trackByFn(index: any, item: any) {
        return item.key;
    }
```

In console the json object is shown like below, which is expected:

```
{
CR1: "aaa"
CR2: "bbb*2"
CR3: "ccc/2"
CR4: "ddd-23"
CR5: ""
CR6: ""
CR7: ""
CR8: ""
CR9: ""
CR10: ""
CR11: ""
}
```

What exactly is changing this view then?

Comment: Updated the question with code and exact issue. CR10, CR11 should be added after CR9 not CR1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keyvalue pipe sorts the keys you provide. as a result 'CR10' < 'CR2' and it appears upper in the list. I suggest keeping your data structure as array of `{key: string, value: string}` objects and eliminate usage of keyvalue pipe

Comment: Thanks, That worked!! It seems keyvalue pipe doesn't work on character based index as I assumed.